# Laravel 5.2: php artisan devuelve "Could not find driver" en terminal

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel, pdo

Estoy adaptando el tema **Socialite** de JOJO Themes en un sitio y me está dando error al ejecutar `php artisan` en la terminal de mi servidor.

Ya realicé la configuración correspondiente a la base de datos y la aplicación en el archivo **.env** y quedó así:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost // Esto lo agregué yo, porque no venía en el brindado
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=basededatos
DB_USERNAME=usuario
DB_PASSWORD=contraseña
```

Comprobé la información de PHP en una ruta personalizada en **routes.php** (que funciona perfectamente):

```
Route::get( '/phpinfo', function () { 
    echo phpinfo()->pdo_mysql;
} );
```

Y me devuelve (la parte importante creo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo visto tengo todo funcionando ... pero me sigue apareciendo:

> [PDOException]
>
> could not find driver

Bueno, se aceptan ideas. Instalar MySQL no es una opción, porque está instalado.

Comment: Has probado esto? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370074/pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-in-laravel

Comment: Sí, MySQL está instalado (y probé el `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` de todas formas), y probé utilizar la ruta completa de php y no funciona de todas formas.

Comment: @Maramal ya lo solucionaste?

Comment: @PabloContreras no, está en pausa "momentáneamente" hasta que encuentre una solución o alternativa.

Comment: @Maramal ok gracias

Comment: Tomando en cuenta que dices "Se aceptan ideas", estás trabajando en un proyecto ya hecho o es uno nuevo, si es nuevo ya corriste "composer install"

Comment: Me imagino que este problema está ya solucionado, (si sí, por favor comparte cómo lo solucionaste), pero si no, ¿podrías poner cómo te conectas a MySQL con PDO?